# Vim displays help at seemingly random moments

Tags: linux, help-system

I face an issue: When I edit a file in Vim, and while editing/scrolling or even just having the file open, the help screen pops up, and I have to leave the help before I can do something again.

It happens very often. I checked with `:set all` if there was any setting that could cause it, but nothing strange stands out.

Would anyone know what could even cause this behavior?

Sorry, since it is on my work computer, I cannot post the set all settings.

Comment: Check if it happens with a clean spawn (do `vim --clean`). And check if somehow the buttons `SHIFT` and `K` are being pressed without your knowing.

Comment: unfortunately the n--clean is an unknown command (also don't see anything in help that looks like it) It even happens without pressing anything, simply keeping the file open and the help may appear.

Comment: Do `vim --clean` from bash. See `:h --clean`

Comment: `just having the file open`... `without pressing anything`: A faulty F1 key on your keyboard, perhaps?

Comment: Or an escape sequence sending something that looks F1